# C# Program addition operator for Point

Tags: c#

I'm using C# XNA and I found when trying to add two points together it won't let me. Is there some way I can add to the Point class to allow this code to run.

```
Point a = new Point(3,4);
Point b = new Point(6,2);
Point c = a + b; //Should equal new Point(9,6);
```

Comment: `var c = new Point(a.X + b.X, a.Y + b.Y);`?

Comment: Theres no way to add on to the Point class to allow use of the + operator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply overload the `+` operator - like this:

```
class Point
{
    public int X { get; private set; }
    public int Y { get; private set; }

    public Point(int x, int y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }

    public static Point operator +(Point p1, Point p2)
    {
        return new Point(p1.X + p2.X, p1.Y + p2.Y);
    }
}
```

Now, your code compiles as work as you expect it to:

```
Point a = new Point(3, 4);
Point b = new Point(6, 2);
Point c = a + b; //Should equal new Point(9,6); - and it is :)
```

More info on operator overloading can be found on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8edha89s.aspx).

Comment: Although it's not explicitly stated, OP probably refers to `System.Drawing.Point` and not a self made `Point` class where, as you described, he could easily overload the operator.

Answer (score 1):

Add to a separate class.

```
public static void Add(this Point a, Point b){
     a.X += b.X;
     a.Y += b.Y;
}
```

Comment: You sure you want to change `a`? In your OP you leave `a` and `b` alone and create a new `Point c`.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a **Size** struct to a **Point** struct , and easily convert between them by passing a Point in to a Size constructor like this:

```
c = a + (new Size(b));
```

Why DOT NET choose to enforce this subtle distinction between intensive and extensive tuples is beyond me.

Comment: example: `Point c = a + (Size)b;`

Answer (score 1):

You could use **extension** methods as shown below

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Point a = new Point(1, 2);
        Point b = new Point(2, 4);

        Point c=a.AddPoints(b);
    }
}

public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static Point AddPoints(this Point x, Point y)
    {
        return new Point(x.X + y.X, x.Y + y.Y);
    }
}
```

Comment: I already answered this with extensions. See above. I just wanted to be able to use the + operator instead of having to use a method to add the two points.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, you could use a static method, extension method and maybe even an operator overload, as other answers suggest.

However, .NET has both `Point` and `Size` to capture a *semantic* distinction:

- `Point` refers to a point, usually compared to an arbitrary reference point.
- `Size` refers to a vector - distance with a direction, or distance X & distance Y.

Adding `Point`s would be meaningless. For example, if `Point`s refer to coordinates on a geographic map - what would their mean? "50° latitude" + "60° latitude" = "110° latitude"? That's why .NET wisely chose not to implement an addition operator.

However, adding `Point` and `Size` can have reasonable meaning - "50° latitude" + "1° latitude distance" = "51° latitude" is a good answer.

**PS.** Notice the similarity to the distinction between `DateTime` and `TimeSpan`.

**TL;DR** - One or both of your `Point`s should actually be a `Size` - change it at the earliest location possible.